# how to print elements of a dictionary that correspond with user input

Tags: python, dictionary, input, user-input

in this problem, i have file.txt that looks like

```
Tanzania:2948
Lesotho:2932
Comoros:2751
Nepal:2702
Yemen:2606
Zimbabwe:2434
Solomon Islands:2427
Benin:2276
Guinea:2247
Mali:2218
Kiribati:2185
Rwanda:2043
Afghanistan:1976
Chad:1945
Ethiopia:1903
Uganda:1868
Burkina Faso:1866
```

etc.

my current code looks like

```
def makeDicts():
 incomeDict = dict()
 countryDict = dict()

 countryList =[]
 gdpList = []
 initialList = []

 with open('lab8.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
   line= line.upper().strip().split(':')
   countryList.append(line[0])
   gdpList.append(line[1])
   initial =line[0][0]
   initialList.append(initial)

  for i in range(len(countryList)):
   incomeDict[countryList[i]] = gdpList[i]

   if initialList[i] not in countryDict:
    countryDict[initialList[i]] = set()
   countryDict[initialList[i]].add( countryList[i])

  return (incomeDict,countryDict)

userinp = input('Enter File Name: ')
incomeDict , countryDict = makeDicts()


while True:
 x = input("Enter a Coutry name or letter or DONE to quit: ")
 x = x.upper()

 if x=='DONE':
  exit()
```

I know the function is made correctly as it was made based on exact instructions but I need to make the lower program which I am having trouble with these are the tasks.

For this exercise, we will write a program that makes use of two dictionaries. The program
will be able to do two different functions:

1. If a country name is entered, the program should report the per capita gross domestic
   product (GDP) of that country.
2. If a letter is entered, the program should report all the countries that it has in the
   system that start with that letter.

Finally, the specifications ask us to prompt the user for either an initial which returns the set of countries that start with that initial, or a country name that returns the corresponding income, or the word “DONE” which exits the program. We can accomplish this using a while loop that will run until the user enters “DONE”. It will check if the user entered text is in any of the dictionaries and return the appropriate value at that key. Write this into a main() function, with the following suggestions:

1. First, to construct the dictionaries, write a line of code like incomeDict , countryDict = makeDicts()
2. Write a while loop and repeated prompt the user for input.
3. After converting the input to upper-case, you should test whether the user typed in a country name or an initial. These can both be accomplished by testing whether the user input is a key in one of the dictionaries. For instance, if the user input is in a variable called x, then ‘x in countryDict’ will test if the user typed in a letter that is the start of one or more country names.
4. If the user types in a letter, report all of the countries that start with that letter: These countries start with F: {'FINLAND', 'FIJI', 'FRANCE'}
5. If the user types in a country name, report the per capita GDP of that country: FINLAND has per capita GDP of 46344
6. If the user types in DONE, then quit the program.
7. For all other inputs, report an error and prompt again.

can you please help me finish this

I have tried the code that I wrote above but I do not know how to scan the dictionarys and produce the output based on the instructions.

I do not know what type of functions or opperators I can use?

Answer (score 0):

After the `if x=='DONE':` line, you will want to say as:

```
 if x == 'DONE':
  exit()
 elif len(x) == 1:
  if x in countryDict:
   print(f"These countries start with {x}: {countryDict[x]}")
  else:
   print(f"No contries start with {x}")
 else:
  if x in incomeDict:
   print(f"{x} has per capita GDP of {incomeDict[x]}")
  else:
   print(f"Country {x} not registered")
```

As a side note, the too small indentation may make the code less readable (IMHO).